# Pre-initialize method inside of class?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have the following class:

```
class A:
    def method_a(name):
        return f"{name} and {name}"

    var1 = method_a("Fred")
```

Is there a way to pre-initialize the method `method_a` so I can force this order inside of my class:

```
class A:
    some pre initialisation of method_a ??how??
    var1 = method_a("Fred")

    def method_a(name):
        return f"{name} and {name}"
```

Comment: No, it's not possible to call a function before it's defined in Python

Comment: It seems that `method_a` does not need to be bound to an instance. Are you sure that it must be a method (notice that you forgot the `self` parameter)

Comment: The method `method_a` should be some static method and the variable `var1` should be some class variable not depending on some instance of A itself.

Comment: You can also define `@classmethod`s that automatically receive the class as their first argument instead of an instance (thereby allowing access to class-level variables — i.e. `cls.var1`).

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) for `classmethod`.